# Apache on Linux, MySql on Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, linux, apache

Is it possible to have a web server (Apache for instance) on a linux machine connecting to a backgroun database server (MySql) on a windows machine?

Comment: Yes it is, without special configuration. But this question shouldn't be in here/is why to vague. Vote to close.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that would be a problem. The connections are usually set up with the combination of Address(IP), User and Password. The syntax should not change between the platforms.

Edit: spelling

Answer (score 2):

Since the communication MySQL protocol (which is platform-neutral) goes over TCP/IP (likewise platform-neutral), the OS of the web server and of the MySQL server is irrelevant.

Usual concerns apply - e.g. by default, a MySQL server only accepts connections from the same computer, and needs to be configured to accept connections from the other server; also, both servers should be as close to each other as possible (topologically), as to reduce communication latency.